# Configure java servlet xml and html form with packages

Tags: java, servlets

I have a package called *asd* and under it a servlet *MyClass*, i am using *web.xml* to configure the servlet and a form tag on *index.html*.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>asd.MyClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyClass</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/asd/MyClass</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the form tag

```
<form action="asd.MyClass" method="get">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I have already tried making another servlet without the package with the same code configured properly and it works. So I image the problem have to do with the configuration of the package in *servlet-class*, *url-pattern* and *action*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should submit to the URL your servlet is mapped to in url-pattern within the servlet-mapping. You need action set to asd/MyClass.

```
<form action="asd/MyClass" method="get">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```